# Node-gyp to generate non Node.js projects?

Tags: node.js, gyp, node-gyp

Can `node-gyp` by used to generate non Node.js addon projects?

For instance, I'd like to use `node-gyp` to generate a typical "Hello, World!" C++ project. Can I do this, and how would I go about it? I'm finding the stock python GYP documentation to lack in examples and description of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can generate regular projects. It does it quite naturally and very nice, actually.